# Check how many files were deleted by date

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, storage

I noticed a lot of storage was freed during the last days of September. How do I check what was deleted/storage freed by date at organization level?

Answer (score 0):

**Please run the below powershell as an admin:**

```
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Echo"
 
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)

#Get Date
#Note: You can adjust the time of Date1 and Date2 according to Today's date.
#$Today= (Get-Date)
$Today = Get-Date -DisplayHint Date
$Date1 = $Today.date.AddDays(-42)
#Date1
$Date2 = $Today.date.AddDays(-11)
#Date2

#Get Recycle bin Items
$DeletedItems = Get-PnPRecycleBinItem | ? {($_.DeletedDate -gt $Date1 -and $_.DeletedDate -lt $Date2)} 
$DeletedItems | Select Title, ItemType, Size, ItemState, DirName, DeletedByName, DeletedDate | Format-table
```

**For example：**

Items in the Recycle bin:

[image]

Powershell:

[image]